# How can i share gif in whatsapp directly without UIactivityViewcontroller and UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to share gif in whatsapp without UIactivityViewcontroller and UIDocumentInteractionController, Is it possible to share gif directly? How? Thanks in advance.

```
NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?image=%@",GIFPathToShare];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// this is identify if whatsapp is already install your device , if yes it open the whatsapp and share the content
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
} else {

    // it shows the alert for no application found
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Without `UIactivityViewcontroller and UIDocumentInteractionController` i think it is not possible.But i'am not sure

Comment: @Gokul I want to share direct in whatsapp

Comment: try with canOpenURL method

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I already tried